# Как обновить версию php на Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, ubuntu

Пытался обновить версию php на сервере Ubuntu 16.04 до 7.3. После установки пишет:

> NOTICE: Not enabling PHP 7.3 FPM by default.
> NOTICE: To enable PHP 7.3 FPM in Apache2 do:
> NOTICE: a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif
> NOTICE: a2enconf php7.3-fpm

При проверке версии на сервер пишет что версия php 7.3. При проверке через какталог в корне сайта пишет, что версия 7.0. Wordpress тоже видит 7.0. После удаления версии php 7.0 с сервера на открываются сайты (500 Internal Server Error).
Как мне обновить  и включить последнюю версию php ?

Comment: Думаю, что первлначально надо было удалить версию 7.0 до того, как ставить версию 7.3 - просто, чтобы не создавть зоопарк версий. А что если сейчас принудительно поставить 7.3? sudo apt-get update и sudo apt-get install php7.3 ?

Comment: `dkg -l | grep php` смотрите какие версии установлены. `ii` - установленный, `rr` - удаленный. Скорее всего не до конца почистили версию `7.0` - для этого найдите установленные пакеты от версии `7.0` и удалите их через команду `dpkg -purge <перечень пакетов через пробел>`. После этого подключите модуль `php7.3-fpm` в `Apache2` командами `a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif` и `a2enconf php7.3-fpm`.

Comment: так вы выполнили то, что предложено в приведённом вами сообщении?